# Element adaptive-icon must be declared

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I use Android Studio 2.3.3 stable and trying to create adaptive icon for Android O

I've created folder `mipmap-anydpi-v26` and file `ic_launcher.xml` with following content

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_adaptive"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

But it says "Element adaptive-icon must be declared".
Target SDK and build tools are both set to 26.

It builds successfully, but I don't have any device to test it, so my question is - does it works?

P.S.: Foreground is valid VectorDrawable

Comment: "I don't have any device to test it" -- test it on an API Level 26 emulator.

Comment: Then buy a device that is capable of running the O Developer Preview and test on it.

Comment: I can confirm that this will work when building with Android Studio version 2.3.3, although I only tested with a bitmap drawable, not with a vector drawable.

Comment: @CommonsWare not everybody has the money to buy a development device and might not have the hardware to run an emulator. Besides that, not everybody wants to use a canary version of Android Studio. Just my 2 cents (pun intended ;-).

Comment: @M66B I just don't want to buy Pixel because it's awful and I'm very happy with my Moto X Force on Nougat

Comment: @DimaRostopira maybe a Nexus 5X is an option

Comment: @M66B: My first comment suggested using an emulator. The OP replied, in a now-deleted comment, that the OP hated the emulator. I then replied with the only other alternative, which was to use O-capable hardware. Regardless of Android Studio version, those are the only two options.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can't see deleted comments ...

Comment: @M66B I said that emulator is like site for adults instead of real things, but some bot probably deleted it

Comment: @M66B what settings should be on gradle for working adaprive icons from studio 2.3.3 ?

Comment: @AndrewS nothing special. Just ignore the Android Studio warnings and it will work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend you to create a Android O virtual device from Android Studio Virtual Device Manager for testing adaptive icons. I am also getting same error in Android Studio 2.3.3. Seems like Android Studio 2.3.3 does not support adaptive icon tag. We need to get Android Studio 3.0 for that.

Even docs for Adaptive Icons in Android developer website shows Android Studio 3.0 screenshots

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/adaptive-icons.html

Edit:- I have checked and found out that Adaptive Icon is working fine in app build from Android Studio 2.3.3 irrespective of "Element adaptive-icon must be declared" error.

Comment: I get an error "Error:(2) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix" and build fails.

Comment: Have you added XML NameSpace <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> at the top of your xml file??

Comment: Yes, thank you. Finally I've found my problem, it is in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

ic_launcher.xml should be like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <adaptive-icon
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <background android:drawable="@color/white"/>
        <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
    </adaptive-icon>
```